# Sitecore Glass Mapper - GlassHtml.RenderImage

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I noticed the tutorial below using GlassHtml.RenderImage where we can specify the width and height of an image.

http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial16/tutorial16.html

```
<%= GlassHtml.RenderImage(Model, x => x.FeaturedImage) %>
```

I tried to use this function using @Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.RenderImage but this SC.GlassHTML doesn't seem to have RenderImage

Can someone please help, what am I  missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried to use this function using
>   @Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.RenderImage but this SC.GlassHTML doesn't
>   seem to have RenderImage

It doesn't work that way; you're trying to access an instance method as if it were static.
Your views need to inherit from `Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<T>` so it exposes the `GlassHtml` methods on your views.

Configure your `/Views/web.config` like this:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView">
    <!-- snipped other lines... -->
```

After that you can access the `GlassView` methods (which call `GlassHtml` methods) in your views like this:

`@RenderImage(x => x.FieldName, new ImageParameters { Width = 80, Height = 80})`

Comment: Or if a config change is too much, just make this particular view use @inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Your.Model.Here>, then use Ruud's RenderImage code.